# fade in a video as soon as its ready to play but wait not less than 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm fading in a video when my page loads, and I'm looking for an idea on how to combine oncanplaythrough with settimeout in a way that the video starts to fade in as soon as possible, but not less than 2 seconds - so other elements on the page can fade in before the video, even if the video loads in faster.

I've been using the following and my assumption was that the video will take some time to load in, but it actually usually loads in even faster than 2 seconds, so it is not ideal for the order of elements on my page to fade in:

```
document.getElementById("v0").oncanplaythrough = function() { document.getElementById("v0").classList.remove('fade-in-vid'); };
```

if the video is not loaded yet and the fade in starts after the 2 seconds, that is fine, but I also want to avoid it waiting an additional 2 seconds if the video can play through already - so I need to check if it can already play through after the 2 seconds wait time - if so, start fading it in immediately.

any ideas? vanilla js only please.

Comment: I've experimented a bit, and this works roughly:
`
setTimeout(function(){ 
    if(document.fonts.ready) {
    document.getElementById("v0").classList.remove('fade-in-vid'); } 
}, 3000); `

but I'm still missing one thing - to wait also for the video to fully load. I've tried adding 
&& document.getElementById("v0").canplaythrough to the if, but its not working, so I guess it cant work as an if condition?